# Is there a library that handles hexagon tiled 2D maps?

Tags: 2d, maps, hexagonal-grid

It would represent a map that is semi-square of arbitrary size. It would have a simple system for representation of the map coordinates, such as 0101 (first column, 1st hex). I'd want the map to be able to tell me the distance between two points and what other hexes lay between those two points, as a list or array.

I don't care as much about the language, but C# or Python would be ideal.

Does one exist?

Comment: This might help, [Mappy](http://www.tilemap.co.uk/mappy.php).

Comment: Look at this: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a library but more of a tutorial. Looking though the tutorial it seems to do everything you requested. It uses C# / XNA.

[Article: Hexagonal Coordinates « Sgt. Conker](http://web.archive.org/web/20100513023947/http://www.sgtconker.com/2009/12/article-hexagonal-coordinates/)

Comment: The version of that code in http://jemginehex.codeplex.com/ includes a variety with the other alignment. [Seeing my own article pop up as an answer is nice.]

Answer (score 4):

The [Cocos 2D library](http://cocos2d.org) has support for rendering hex tile maps. I have not used it, but the library has been around for years and seems quite popular.

That might be more for rendering than for doing calculations on the hex map though. Fortunately what you ask for is quite simple to implement anyway, especially if you use a good x/y coordinate system for your hexes. See: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html#hex

Answer (score 4):

[Pieter Geerkens](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/26606/pieter-geerkens) (who is here on stackexchange) has a [C# library for hexagons](https://github.com/pgeerkens/HexGridUtilitiesForGames).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the *Java* version of the *Tiled Map Editor* supports hexagonal maps. Have a look for yourself at: http://www.mapeditor.org/

Comment: Hex map support was added to Tiled (the modern C++ version) again back in version 0.11. http://doc.mapeditor.org/en/latest/reference/tmx-changelog/#tiled-0-11